# How to write a wrapper using existing built-in UDFs in Hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create new UDFs in Hive. Some of the UDFs are just a modification of the built-in UDF in Hive.

e.g **median** function is written as

```
select percentile(cast(column as BIGINT), 0.5) from table_name
```

This means, whenever I have to calculate median, I have to rewrite a query as specified above. Is there any way I can create a new UDF and wrap the existing UDF **percentile** in the java code?

How to create a new UDF which will be a wrapper of existing built-in UDFs?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `callUDF` function:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{callUDF, lit}

val df = Seq((1L, 3L), (2L, 5L), (3L, 4L)).toDF("id", "x")
df.select(callUDF("percentile", $"x", lit(0.5)))
```

So median would be a function like this:

```scala
def median(expr: org.apache.spark.sql.Column): org.apache.spark.sql.Column = {
  callUDF("percentile", expr, lit(0.5))
}

df.select(median($"x"))
```

You cannot use nest UDF calls though. UDF wraps a function which operates on extracted values not columns.

Comment: @eliasah     
I am implementing UDFs in Java. So how do I write above UDF- median which will internally call Percentile?

Comment: You can write a function from `Column` -> `Column` which is a different thing that writing an UDF. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. So this would not be UDF, correct? This would be just function which I would call. So how would I use it on Spark-SQL shell?

Comment: Thats correct, it won't be an UDF. Truth be told I am not sure if it is possible to do it directly in SQL shell.

Answer (score 0):

All hive udfs can be accessed from spark sql. You can reigster you own udf in spark sql and use the hive udfs in that.   sqlContext.udf.register((x, percentileValue)=> { // implement method using those params})

Comment: I am implementing UDFs in Java. So how do I write above UDF- median which will internally call Percentile?